# Adding a text field in Customer Grid

Tags: admin, customer, grid

I need to add a custom search text field into the customer grid.
Would it be possible without changing the default grid template?
thanks

Comment: By using plugins you can achieve this

Comment: any specific suggestion Pavan? thanks